# savedInstanceState is always null value in onCreate

Tags: android

This is my onCreate method in a class which is subclass of fragment

```
static  int counter = 0;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState == null) { //made for first time
        Log.d("came in", "Came in");
        counter = 0;
    } else {
        counter = savedInstanceState.getInt("counter", 0);
    }
}
```

this is my savedInstanceState method

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.d("hi there", ""+counter); // this is printing hi there 3
    outState.putInt("counter", counter);//key value pair
}
```

but in onCreate method savedInstanceState is always null and printing came in.

Comment: The saved state is only restored when the activity has frozen state, i.e. mostly on configuration changes (rotation and the like). There is no saved state, when you e.g. re-create the activity from scratch. Did you expect the saved state to be more persistent than it is?

Comment: I want to get counter variable when i rotate screen.

Answer (score 1):

Override `protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and see if you can get your values there.

Comment: onRestoreInstanceState method is not there in super class. I am extending Fragment class.

Comment: get it from the parent Activity oRestoreInstanceState() and pass it to the visible fragment via some method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save your value in your fragment host activity(Activity in which your fragment is defined). From host activity, you have to extract that value and access it in your fragment subclass.

Answer (score 0):

try change you method onSaveInstanceState to:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){    
    Log.d("hi there", ""+counter); // this is printing hi there 3
    outState.putInt("counter", counter);//key value pair
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState); // call super after put int
}
```